# How can I fix this update issue?

Tags: 8, updating

I have updated a Drupal site from 8.5.3 to 8.6.3 and got the following error related to the webform module. Can anyone help me fix this?

> webform module
> Update #8108
>
> Failed: Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'block_content_field_data.reusable' in 'where clause': SELECT base_table.revision_id AS revision_id, base_table.id AS id FROM {block_content} base_table INNER JOIN {block_content_field_data} block_content_field_data ON block_content_field_data.id = base_table.id WHERE (block_content_field_data.reusable IN (:db_condition_placeholder_0)) AND (block_content_field_data.default_langcode IN (:db_condition_placeholder_1)); Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 1 ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadByProperties()(line 541 of C:\xampp\htdocs\html86-13nov\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase.php).

Comment: You need to run the database updates. If you're getting that message during such an update, just stop and run them again

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the database updates. If you have Drush, just run `drush @YOUR_ENV_ALIAS updb`. Otherwise, log in into your website and go through the update process from https://example.com/update.php. (Replace *example.com* with the domain name used from the site.)